# Use of the TLB with regards to ‘Locality of Reference’.?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I know what TLB is and I know what LoR is but I cant answer the question how they are "connected" together ? Is the main point that TLB contains a most frequently used entries and that can be described as part of Locality of Reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider how many TLB entries you need for 10 memory reads of 32 bits each, when those entries are 10 bytes, 10 kilobytes, or 10 megabytes apart. TLB entries are very scarce; LoR reduces the number of TLB entries needed.

Comment: Ok if I get it right what You mean is that because we know that data/programs tends to cluster we have a TLB with much less entries needed etc. So in simple terms to answer my question I could simply describe how does LoR works ?  Am I getting that correct ?

Comment: In simple terms, yes. Your teacher might be looking for a more detailed answer, but how detailed probably depends on your class. At a technical university level I'd be looking for a more mathematically grounded answer.

Answer (score 0):

The connection between the two concepts is that TLBs rely on LoR. Because programs tend to access memory close together at any point in time, a page table entry cached in a TLB after being accessed is likely to be reused frequently within a short span of time.

If processes accessed memory randomly TLBs would be completely ineffective because the MMU would have no way to predict what entries should be stored in the TLB.